# how to make java decompiler generate an error

Tags: java, decompiler

I was curious about this question.

Is there a line of code or some way that I can make my program generate an error when being decompiled?

Its not a huge problem since usually it cannot read the code correctly anyways but it would be interesting to completely hide your source code.

Comment: There is the possibility to generate bytecode that simply has no valid java equivalent (e.g. a duff-device). Some imaginative, nested loop constructs making liberal used of break/continue (label) are also prone to break when decompiled (more a sign of the limits of the decompiler than an impossibility).

Answer (score 2):

First off, obfuscation is never the answer. Whatever you think you need obfuscation for, you don't. And it won't stop anyone knowledgeable and determined from reverse engineering your app anyway.

But as for the actual question, it depends. Some decompilers are dumb and easy to break. Some, like Krakatau, are much more robust. There are still ways to prevent Krakatau from decompiling, but nothing that would stop a skilled reverse engineer for long.

There are also a lot of interesting tricks you can play with bytecode and the classfile format, though some of them are specific to Oracle's JVM and thus marginally reduce portability. I've written crackmes demonstrating some interesting bytecode tricks I discovered (particularly [this](http://crackmes.de/users/warsaw/java_crackme_1.1/), [this](http://crackmes.de/users/warsaw/java_crackme_3/), [this](http://crackmes.de/users/warsaw/java_crackme_1.2/), and [this](http://crackmes.de/users/warsaw/invisible_java_crackme/)). Most of those will foil any tool other than Krakatau. But this is mostly of academic interest.

Comment: like i said, i was just interested in knowing if there is a way or not ;) thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible, however, if you wish to protect your intellectual property, you may use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to obfuscate class, method and field names to make decompiled code hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on how the decompiler works, you can use something like hosemocha. But that is really really old java.

http://mguessan.free.fr/java/securite/HoseMocha.java